# Syntax error in shell script with process substitution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process-substitution

I have this shell script which I use to back up my system. There is a line:

```
tar -Pzcpf /backups/backup.tar.gz --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups --exclude=var/log / 2> >(grep -v 'socket ignored' >&2)
```

As you can see, I have been trying to filter out the annoying, useless "socket ignored" error by tar, using [this blog post](http://wundsam.net/2011/03/27/filtering-stderr-or-how-to-get-rid-of-tars-socket-ignored-message/).

What I get from shell upon execution is:

> /bin/sysback: line 45: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
>   /bin/sysback: line 45:`tar -Pzcpf /backups/backup --directory=/
>   --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups --exclude=var/log / 2> >(grep -v 'socket ignored' >&2)'

Comment: I think `2> >(` should be `2>(`.

Comment: Didn't give a syntax error after this change, but didn't filter out the output either.

Comment: The >(...) process substitution syntax is a non-standard feature, and your shell apparently doesn't support it. Use a different shell, or perhaps a newer version of bash.

Comment: I stand corrected, `2> >(` seems to be the way to redirect stderr into a subshell, and running `(echo "FOO";echo "FOO" >&2) 2> >(grep -v FOO >&2)` outputs a single "FOO" with GNU bash 4.2.24. What shell are you using?

Comment: Quite clearly not Bash, or Bash in POSIX mode, probably from `cron`.

Comment: I am using bash on Debian, `ps -p $$` produces `24831 pts/0    00:00:00 bash` and `cat /etc/debian_version` says `6.0.5`.

Comment: `cron` will run your scripts using `sh`, which on a Debian system is `dash`, not `bash`. Adding a `!#/bin/bash` to your script may help (but I'm not as familiar with `cron` as I should be, and have no direct experience with Debian).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The syntax you've used is a bash extension to the basic shell syntax, so you must take care to run your script with bash. (Ksh also has `>(…)` process substitution but doesn't support it after a redirection. Zsh would be fine.)

Given the error message you're getting, you are running this script in bash, but in its POSIX compatibility mode, not in full bash mode. Take care to invoke your script with an explicit `#!/bin/bash` line. `#!/bin/sh` won't do, even if `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to bash, because bash runs in POSIX mode if it's invoked under the name `sh`. Always invoke bash by name if you use bash features.

Also take care not to set the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` or to pass the `--posix` option on the command line if you want to use bash features.

Alternatively, don't use this bash-specific syntax; use a portable construct such as the one proposed by [Stephane Rouberol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120598/syntax-error-in-shell-script-with-process-substitution/12121244#12121244).

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
 tar -Pzcpf /backups/backup.tar.gz --directory=/ \
     --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts \
     --exclude=backups --exclude=var/log 2>&1 | grep -v 'socket ignored'
```

Comment: Even though what you are offering here, is a legitimate alternative to the solution, I will be choosing @Gilles solution as the correct answer, since it answers he point posed by the question. Thank you for the very good answer though.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that on gentoo also if sh is a link to /bin/bash if you call the script with 'sh "scriptname"' it doesn't run it as a bash script  and fail with:

```
matchmorethan.sh: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
matchmorethan.sh: line 34: `done < <( cat $matchfile )'
```

So if you need to use the Process Substitution feature you need to specifically run it with bash. But I didn't find any reference to this.

Comment: Using the `sh` name makes bash set the POSIX flag, same as `set -o posix`. Search for "in posix mode" in bash's documentation; it talks about the details quite a lot..

Comment: Also, referenced from that documentation, http://tiswww.case.edu/~chet/bash/POSIX

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't have to go for such a redirection in std error when GNU tar provides options to ignore the "socket ignored" warning.

```
tar --warning='no-file-ignored' -Pzcpf /backups/backup.tar.gz --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups --exclude=var/log / 2> new.err
```

[You could find the original link with more ignore options here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_27.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but specially thanks for the link :)